# Detect & inject code to main form of .net application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, code-injection

Simply I want to make a 3rd party software to detect the .net application if it's vb.net or c# and inject few lines of code to it's main form, initialize the component part.

Where do I start ?

Comment: I believe this to be Malware..

Comment: No not really. I am working on a licensing system.

Comment: You do know that it takes just a few minutes to learn what this thing does and create a patcher type app, no?

Comment: I know that it's easy to crack .net, yes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to "change" the code inside a external `DLL`, however if you want to modify a argument going in or a result coming back that is not hard to do. The process of intercepting the call to either modify the input or output is called "[Hooking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking)".

In C# there is a easy to use library that does most of the work for you called [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/), this will allow you to intercept calls and replace the return values with your own results.

```
static IntPtr CreateFile_Hooked(
    String InFileName, 
    UInt32 InDesiredAccess, 
    UInt32 InShareMode, 
    IntPtr InSecurityAttributes,
    UInt32 InCreationDisposition, 
    UInt32 InFlagsAndAttributes, 
    IntPtr InTemplateFile)
{
    try
    {
        Main This = (Main)HookRuntimeInfo.Callback;

        lock (This.Queue)
        {
        if (This.Queue.Count < 1000)
                This.Queue.Push(InFileName);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    // call original API...
    return CreateFile(
        InFileName, 
        InDesiredAccess, 
        InShareMode, 
        InSecurityAttributes, 
        InCreationDisposition,
        InFlagsAndAttributes, 
        InTemplateFile);
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to modify, just add few lines of code into already built .net application but I need them added to intialize component part.